# Dynamically created component recordId

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm dynamically creating a Lightning Component to display a link. The link is on a field on the record. This component will be called from a parent component that exists on the Record Detail page (on the community record detail page).
The problem is that this dynamically created component doesn't seem to get the `recordId` from the detail page.

Component markup:

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="force:hasRecordId" controller="My_Controller">

    <aura:attribute name="myLink" type="string"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>

    Component works
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.myLink}">
        <a href="{!v.myLink}" target="blank_">Click my link!</a>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Component controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    if (recordId){
        var action = component.get("c.getMyRecord");
        action.setParams({objId: recordId, fields: "MyLink__c"});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS"){
                var record = response.getReturnValue();
                var link = record.MyLink__c;
                component.set("v.myLink", link);
            }
            else{
                console.error("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of component working, but no link]

The component works, I can see the text. But there is no value in `myLink`.
Using the Chrome debugger I see that it fails because `recordId` is undefined.
So is this a thing, dynamically created components don't get the RecordId, even thought they `implement="force:hasRecordId"`?

Comment: I think your question is probably answered by [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241412/forcehasrecordid-cascade/241417): the record Id doesn't cascade down to components that aren't embedded directly in the record page at the top level.

Comment: Yeah, that does answer my question. SIGH.